# Ubuntu 18.04 Rhythmbox starts when Skype call is finished

Tags: 18.04, skype, rhythmbox

I have weird problem. When I finish a Skype call, in Ubuntu 18.04 then Rhythombox automatically starts playing music?!
This happens even if Rhythmbox was paused before the Skype call began.

I'm not even sure where to start debugging this problem.

Comment: @PRATAP No, it's though apt-get. Version 8.34.0.78, invoked as skypeforlinux.

Comment: In only get that the the package is already installed: me@mysmashine:~$ sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
skypeforlinux is already the newest version (8.34.0.78).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this might be related to PulseAudio. Had the same issue a long time ago. Try fixing it by opening `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and commenting out the line `load-module module-role-cork` by putting a `#` in front of it. After that, restart the PulseAudio deamon:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio -D
```

If that doesn't help, you might need to at least log out of your user account or even restart the whole PC.

Comment: Thanks. Tried you changes and at least audio did not kick back this time i was skyping. Fingers crossed it's permanent...

Comment: Awesome! Should be permanent :)